# Getting all the values in one query that aren't in another with a group by

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, intersection

Given that I am using Redshift, how would I get the counts for a query that asks:

Given table A and table B, give me all the count of values in Table A for that grouping that aren't in table B;

So if table A and B look like:

Table A

```
Id | Value
==========
 1 | "A"
 1 | "B"
 2 | "C"
```

And table B:

```
Id | Value
==========
 1 | "A"
 1 | "D"
 2 | "C"
```

I would want:

```
Id | Count
==========
 1 |  1
 2 |  0
```

Comment: sorry didn't understand your logic

Answer (score 1):

Use `except` and subquery

```
with a as
(
select 1 as id, 'A' as v
union all
select 1,'B'
union all
select 2,'C'
),b as
(
select 1 as id, 'A' as v
union all
select 1,'D'
union all
select 2,'C'
), c as
(
select id,v from a except select id,v from b
)
select id,sum ( (select count(*) from c where c.id=a.id and c.v=a.v))
from a group by id
```

output

```
id  cnt
1   1
2   0
```

[online demo which will work in redshift](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=54f43129102a7e707cbada7bb0f58143)

Comment: `minus` is Oracle specific. The SQL standard uses `except` - as Redshift is based on Postgres, I assume it would be `except` in Redshift as well.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks i have edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use `left join` and `group by`:

```
select a.id, sum( (b.id is null)::int )
from a left join
     b
     on a.id = b.id and a.value = b.value
group by a.id;
```